# defaultdict is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python 3.2.

```
import collections
d = defaultdict(int)
```

run

```
NameError: name 'defaultdict' is not defined
```

Ive restarted Idle. I know collections is being imported, because typing

```
collections
```

results in

```
<module 'collections' from '/usr/lib/python3.2/collections.py'>
```

also help(collections) shows me the help including the defaultdict class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read about `import`. It only adds the names you specify to your namespace. You could, for instance, use `from collections import defaultdict`, or you could refer to `defaultdict` as `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: What post here gave you the idea that that would work? Perhaps it can be corrected if some answer forgot to use the right import statement..

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
```

It might behoove you to read about [the `import` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).

Answer (score 45):

You're not importing `defaultdict`. Do either:

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

or

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to write:

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

Answer (score 0):

Defaultdict is a container like dictionaries present in the module collections. To access defaultdict you would either have to modify your import statement to -

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

or use -

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
```

to be able to use defaultdict